# dynamic root host switching

Tags: symlink, g-wan, virtual-hosts

I have several projects in the gwan server, so I need to switch the vhosts when I test the project from other machine in my local network.
I made a symbolic link of a vhost as the root host.
But gwan reported that "no 'root' #host for listener 0.0.0.0_80".
No matter it is a relative or absolute path link, same error occurred.

Is there any way to achieve the dynamic root host switching?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try v4.25 posted this morning? v4.24 had compiler-optimization issues that prevented some code from executing (resulting in empty files on some platforms).

Comment: i tried v4.1.25 without -d, the result was "no root host for the listener 0.0.0.0_80 ; in the log file, there was error: "[Mon Feb 04 03:23:32 2013 GMT] * can't parse 'chart.c'; run without -d (daemon mode)
[Mon Feb 04 03:23:32 2013 GMT] Error(s) in chart.c"

Comment: when tried with -d, in the trace file, there were a long list of started children. The pid filename kept changing in the gwan folder.

Comment: v4.1.25 still can not use symbolic link as a root host.

Comment: Some info:
i made a symlink "serverEnabled" pointing to gwan_4_1_25 folder(the whole tree is extracted from the downloaded gwan. Under the listener 0.0.0.0_80, i set the vhosts and made a symlink as root host pointing to one of the vhosts.)
cd to serverEnabled then sudo ./gwan, it works.
open the log file, the reported paths of the root and vhosts are absolute paths, not including the symlink of "serverEnabled".